# Tumblr themes issue on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

This user on SO seems to be having [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447402/tumblr-theme-with-jquery-javascript-broken-suddenly) with a suddenly broken Tumblr theme.  It's off topic for SO, since he's basically saying that his Tumblr blog is broken and he doesn't know what to do.  Do you think this is on topic for Webapps?  If so, I'll flag for migration, else I'll vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things and whatnot about Tumblr are generally on topic on Nothing to Install. That ranges from themes to tags and dashboard things to tags again.

The question on Stack Overflow has been deleted, so no idea what it was.

Since it's deleted, there's generally no need to flag for migration as they'll probably find their way here on their own. Hopefully with a question that includes as much info as necessary to help other users solve the problem.